# Unable to edit a cell formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have a worksheet sent by my boss with bunch of formulas to update. But when I'm trying to change a cell's formula and press enter the formula is not updated. For e.g. =a1+b2 updated as =a2+b3. But it remains as =a1+b2. Can someone help me in solving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the worksheet locked at all? Can you edit any other cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. The excel is having some data connections and macros . Cell change is working fine when that data connection and macros is disabled. Till now I have enabled the data connection and tried to update the formula.